# Do I have to add yum-cron to the crontab?

Tags: centos, cron, yum

Content of `/etc/sysconfig/yum-cron`:

```
15:14:57 # vim /etc/sysconfig/yum-cron

# if MAILTO is set and the mail command is available, the mail command
# is used to deliver yum output

# by default MAILTO is unset, so crond mails the output by itself
# example:  MAILTO=root
MAILTO=test@test.com

# you may set SYSTEMNAME if you want your yum emails tagged differently
SYSTEMNAME="UHSPAASTREAM06"

# you may set DAYS_OF_WEEK to the days of the week you want to run
# default is every day
DAYS_OF_WEEK="12345"

# which day should it do cleanup on?  defaults to 0 (Sunday).  If this day 
isn't in the
# DAYS_OF_WEEK above, it'll never happen
CLEANDAY="2"

# set to yes to make the yum-cron service to wait for transactions to 
complete
SERVICE_WAITS=yes

# set maximum time period (in seconds) for the yum-cron service to wait for
# transactions to complete.  The default is 300 seconds (5 minutes)
SERVICE_WAIT_TIME=300
```

I want the yum-cron to run weekly at 11am. I don't see anywhere to specify the time. Should I create a cron tab?

Answer (score 3):

As soon as one installs `yum-cron`, new files related to `cron` are created at the following locations: `/etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron` and `/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron`.

If your system contains the `yum-utils` package, then one could determine which files were installed with `repoquery -l yum-cron`. This command provides output such as the following snippet.

```
/etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron
/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron
/etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf
/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/system/yum-cron.service
/usr/sbin/yum-cron
/usr/share/doc/yum-cron-3.4.3
/usr/share/doc/yum-cron-3.4.3/COPYING
/usr/share/man/man8/yum-cron.8
```

Immediately, we can see what the manual has to say with `man yum-cron`. Basically, it's not much; it reveals that configuration files are used over command-line arguments.

Each of the directories, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, and `/etc/cron.monthly` are designed to store scripts that should be executed periodically by `cron`. The exact timing for each period can be revealed by reading the configuration file for `cron` with a command such as `cat /etc/anacrontab`. There are many `cron` servers. I use `anacron`. You may use a different `cron` package.

So, no: one does not need to create a job for `cron` because the job already exists. One could ...

- **accept the default `cron` schedules**,
- modify the default `cron` schedules, or
- remove the cron jobs for `yum-cron` and make your own `cron` job (`crontab -e`).

Comment: I'm also getting a error of (root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/yum-cron) and Failed to send an email to UHSPAASTREAM01: [Errno 111] Connection refused.